# Devise: how can I access the helper methods in all my controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, methods, devise, twitter-bootstrap, undefined-reference

I'm trying to implement a devise sign in form in my nav bar header(twitter bootstrap), but it just tells me that resource isn't a defined method.

Do I need to somehow inherit the devise helper methods to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to creating a custom sign in page, it doesn't have anything to do with your controller, it has to do with accessing things in your view, through the helper of helper methods.  You want to add them to your application_helper.rb file.  There is an overview of the method here:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app

In a nutshell, you basically want to add this to yours application_helper.rb

```
def resource_name
 :user
end

def resource
  @resource ||= User.new
end

def devise_mapping
  @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
end
```

I have used this a bunch of times in all my projects to make custom sign in forms in the navbar when I use twitter bootstrap.  It works great and doesn't require you to change any other code anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. As a matter of conventions is to best to keep it in the application helper or a separate authentication helper?

Comment: You need to put it in `application_helper.rb` since it will be on the navbar of the layout and it has the potential to show up in any of your controllers' views. Only helper methods that matter to a particular controller should go in that controller's helper file. This is why you got the error in the first place, devise's helper file has those in there and when you call those methods outside it's controller it doesn't know what methods you are talking about. In short, if you need it accessible everywhere, put it in application_helper.rb, otherwise just put it in that controller's helper file.

Comment: I know this question hasn't been active for 2 years now. But I'm facing this same problem of accessing **devise's** resource helpers. The thing is I have more than one resource, specifically, one for customer and one for admin. How can I achieve this, given my case?